# Дополнить строку другой строкой

Tags: строки, javascript

Опишите функцию strPad(), которая дополняет строку 
другой строкой до заданной длины

```
Функция принимает следующие аргументы:
input – входная строка
fullLen – длина конечной строки
fillStr – дополняющая строка
fillType – 'FILL_RIGHT', 'FILL_LEFT' или 'FILL_BOTH'.
strPad('star', 10,'-*-') //star-*--*-
strPad('star', 8,'-*-', 'FILL_LEFT') //-*--star
strPad('star', 8,'*', 'FILL_BOTH') //**star**
```

Я как не мучился но более этого кода выдавить не могу:

```
function strPad(input, fullen, fillstr, filltype) {
var a = input.split(''); //4
var b = fillstr.split('');//3
var c = a.length + b.length;//7
var res = [];

while(res.length<=fullen.length){
    for(var i=0; a.length > i; i++){
        return res += a[i];
    }
console.log(res);
}
}
strPad('star', 10,'-*-','B');
```

но проблема в том что все равно не выводит хотя бы 1/5 решения задачи.
И еще 1 проблема:

```
var a = [s,t,a,r];
var b = [*,*,-]
var c = a.length + b.length // длина 7
var d = a+b;
d.length // длина 12. Почему??
```

Comment: strPad( без доп.параметров ):
 
   function strPad(str, len, pad){
        var buff=''; 
        for(i=0; i<len; ++i) buff+=pad; 
        buff = buff.substring(0,len-str.length); 
        return str+buff
    }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давайте по порядку. Во-первых, ваш код задачу не решает совершенно.

```
while(res.length<=fullen.length){
    for(var i=0; a.length > i; i++){
        return res += a[i];
    }
    console.log(res);
}
```

Здесь вы добавляете к результату символы исходной строки. Точнее, вы этого не делаете, так как условие `res.length<=fullen.length` всегда будет ложным. `res` - массив, у него есть свойство `length`, отражающее количество элементов в нём. А вот `fullen` - число, у него такого свойства нет, `fulllen.length = undefined`. Так как в начале цикла массив `res` пуст, то условие приводится к виду `0 <= undefined`, что равно `false`, поэтому цикл `while` не выполнится ни разу.

Во-вторых, ваш вопрос про

```
d.length // длина 12. Почему??
```

В JavaScript оператор + неприменим к массивам. При сложении объектов, к которым не применяется оператор сложения, JS попытается привести их к таким типам, которые он сможет сложить. В данном случае JS приводит оба массива к строкам. Получается сложение двух строк - `'s,t,a,r'` и `'*,*,-'`. Вместе с запятыми получится как раз 12 символов.

Теперь про ваш алгоритм в общем. Для того, чтобы сложить две строки, совершенн необязательно переводить их в массивы и складывать посимвольно. На мой взгляд, алгоритм должен быть таким:

1. Вычисляем длину, на которую нужно увеличить исходную строку (`fulllen - input.len`)
2. Повтрояем строку `fillstr` несколько раз, пока не полусим строку длиной больше, чем длина, на которую ужно увеличить исходную строку. Обрезаем полученную строку до необходимой длины.
3. Присоединяем эту строку справа или слева к исходной строке (в зависимости от режима).

В случеа `FILL_BOTH` алгоритм будет посложнее - придётся собирать отдельно строки для присоединения справа и слева, так как если длина строки - нечётное число, то слева или справа придётся присоединять строку на один исмвол длиннее.

Вот примерный код для `FILL_RIGHT`. Для остальных режимов, думаю, сделаете самостоятельно.

```
var inputLen = input.length;
var fillLen = length - fullen;
var repeats = Math.ceil(fillLen / fillstr.length + 1);
// Приём, позволяющий повторить строку нужное количество раз. Читайте про конструктор Array и метод join
var fillStr = Array(repeats).join(fillstr).substr(0, fillLen);
return input + fillStr;
```

Comment: @fori1ton, впервые вижу применение конструкции `Array(число)`.

Comment: @alvoro, мы всё когда-нибудь видим впервые. Однако такая конструкция действительно существует: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @fori1ton, я и до этого знал что делает Array(число). Меня удивило то, что эта конструкция может быть полезна.

Answer (score 4):

Отвечу не по порядку.

1) Цитирую (исправив ошибки в коде):

```
var a = ['s','t','a','r'];
var b = ['*','*','-'];
var c = a.length + b.length // длина 7
var d = a+b;
d.length // длина 12. Почему??
```

Вы неправильно складываете массивы. Пояснения:

```
// Вот такая строчка
var d = a + b;

// равносильна этой
var d = a.toString() + b.toString();

// и вот этой
var d = a.join() + b.join();

// что это дает на выходе
// "s,t,a,r*,*,-" ровно 12 символов
```

Как правильно:

```
// Если нужен массив
var d = [].concat.apply([], [a, b]);
// Вывод: Array [ "s", "t", "a", "r", "*", "*", "-" ]

// Если нужна строка
var d = [].concat.apply([], [a, b]).join("");
// Вывод: "star**-"
```

2) Цитирую как есть

```
function strPad(input, fullen, fillstr, filltype) {
    var a = input.split(''); //4
    var b = fillstr.split(''); //3
    var c = a.length + b.length; //7
    var res = [];

    // Первая ошибка: fullen - это число. Метода length возвращает 'undefined'.
    // Цикл ни разу не выполняется, поскольку условие всегда ложно
    while (res.length <= fullen.length) {
        for (var i = 0; a.length > i; i++) {
            // Вторая ошибка: после return функция завершает выполнение
            // Итого, если исправили первую ошибку, функция выполнит 1 итерацию while
            // Затем из-за приведения типов переменная res станет строкой
            // После чего функция вернет строку "s" и завершит свое выполнение
            return res += a[i];
        }
        // До сюда выполнение никогда не доходит, поэтому вывода в консоль нет.
        console.log(res);
    }
}
strPad('star', 10, '-*-', 'B');
```

Answer (score 0):

Я реализовал так, может кому пригодится.

```
function strPad(input, fullLen, fillStr, fillType){
        if(input.length<fullLen){
            var str='', strLeft='', strRight='',i=0;
            var size=fullLen-input.length;
            for(var j = 0; j < size; j++){
                    if(i == fillStr.length)
                        i =0 ;
                str+=fillStr[i];
                i++;
            }
            strLeft = str.slice(0,(str.length/2));
            strRight = str.slice((str.length/2));
            switch(fillType){
                case 'FILL_LEFT': return str+input;
                case 'FILL_BOTH': return strLeft+input+strRight;
                default: return input+str;
            }
        }else 
            return input
    }
```